# Cloudflare Workers FETCH POST Type Error Failed to execute function

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Multiple people have brought up issues similar to mine in this community and cloudflare's community. It still seems largely unsolved so I’m asking in hopes of a solution.

I’m trying to create a feature for users to sign up through mailchimp. User info goes from browser to workers to mail chimp. I’m getting the following errors:

1. TypeError: Failed to execute function: parameter 1 is not of type
   ‘Response’. at line 0, col -2
2. Request.Body is not being read

Request from Client:

```js
        const response = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:8787/signup",
          data: {
            MERGE0: email,
            MERGE1: firstName,
            MERGE2: lastName,
          },
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        });
```

Workers part 1 (function to read request body):
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/read-post

```js
async function readRequestBody(request) {
  const { headers } = request
  const contentType = headers.get('content-type') || ''

  if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
    return JSON.stringify(await request.json())
  } else if (contentType.includes('application/text')) {
    return request.text()
  } else if (contentType.includes('text/html')) {
    return request.text()
  } else if (contentType.includes('form')) {
    const formData = await request.formData()
    const body = {}
    for (const entry of formData.entries()) {
      body[entry[0]] = entry[1]
    }
    return JSON.stringify(body)
  } else {
    // Perhaps some other type of data was submitted in the form
    // like an image, or some other binary data.
    return 'a file'
  }
}
```

Workers part 2 (to Post JSON File to Mail Chimp):
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/post-json

```js
async function gatherResponse(response) {
  const { headers } = response
  const contentType = headers.get('content-type') || ''
  if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
    return JSON.stringify(await response.json())
  } else if (contentType.includes('application/text')) {
    return response.text()
  } else if (contentType.includes('text/html')) {
    return response.text()
  } else {
    return response.text()
  }
}
```

Workers Part 3 (to Handle Post Request):

```js
async function eventHandler(request) {
  const pathname = request.url

  try {
    if (pathname.indexOf('signup') !== -1) {
      const reqBody = await readRequestBody(request)
      const { MERGE0, MERGE1, MERGE2 } = reqBody

      // Construct req data
      const data = {
        members: [
          {
            email_address: MERGE0,
            status: 'subscribed',
            merge_fields: {
              FNAME: MERGE1,
              LNAME: MERGE2,
            },
          },
        ],
      }

      const postData = JSON.stringify(data)

      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `auth ${MAILCHIMP_API_KEY}`,
        },
        body: postData,
      }

      const url = `https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${MAILCHIMP_AUDIENCE_ID}`
      const res = await fetch(url, options)
      const results = await gatherResponse(res)
      return results
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(eventHandler(event.request))
})
```

A few other posts I’ve referenced:

- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/fetch-with-post-method-ignores-body/147758/3
- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-post-with-a-body-as-readable-stream/211335
- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/using-get-fetch-for-api-javascript-worker/98297

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
event.respondWith(eventHandler(event.request))
```

The `event.respondWith()` function needs to take a `Response` object as its parameter. However, your `eventHandler()` function does not return a `Response`. In some cases, the function does not return a result at all, and in other cases, it returns a string.

In cases where you don't want to modify the request/response, you can have `eventHandler` pass through the request to origin like so:

```
return fetch(request);
```

In cases where you have received a response from the origin, and you want to return it directly to the client unmodified, you should just `return repsonse` instead of `return response.text()`.

In cases where you have created some new response text that you want to return, you need to wrap it in a `Response`, like:

```
return new Respnose(text, {headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}});
```